# How solve this - Using the injected `container` is deprecated. Ember 2.3

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How solve this follow message em emberjs 2.3

After upgrade version this start appear.

`Using the injected container is deprecated. Please use the getOwner helper instead to access the owner of this object`

Comment: Take a look at the [2.3 blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_introducing-owners-and-deprecating-containers)

Comment: Maybe its ember-simple-auth or another ember addon? Thats still using the old behavior at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kitler mentioned, [Ember's changelog](http://emberjs.com/blog/) is a good place to check for how to handle deprecations, but sometimes it can be confusing if you're new to Ember.

Search your code for `this.container` or `export function initialize(application, container)`. Replace that with something like this:

```
let owner = Ember.getOwner(this);
owner.lookup('whatever:was:in:this.container.lookup');
```

Making that change should silence the deprecation message and fix your app.